# cannot pass array in a function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning javascript and I want to fill an array in one function and pass it as a parameter in the second function. I have the following code but for some reason it is not working.

```
function gameplay(tmp) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if (xTrans >= tmp[0] - 1
            && xTrans < tmp[0]
            && zTrans <= tmp[1] - 1
            && zTrans > tmp[1])
        {
            //some code here
        }
    }
}

function fillMap() {
    var bounds = new Array();
    for (var y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++) {
            if (map[y][x] == '1') {
                bounds[length] = 4 * x;
                length++;
                bounds[length] = -y - 4 * y;
                length++;
            }
        }
    }
    return bounds;
}
```

and I call like this:

```
var tmp = fillMap();
gameplay(tmp);
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error message, or is the output/result simply not what you expect?

Comment: Make sure your code runs at all. The `length` variable is not defined. I assume you want `bounds.push(...)` instead. If you are new to arrays in JS, I recommend to a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Methods .

Comment: length is defined and the message i get when im trying to print the array is that it is empty.

Comment: Where is `map` defined?

Comment: In for(var y=0; y<map.length ;y++), map ss global variable? Is It initiate with what value?

Comment: It's a global variable and filled with ones and zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this just to confirm what happens when you have a clear and obvious input:

```
function fillMap() {
var map = [[0]];
```

That should give you the output of: [4, -5]

Some potential issues

- map isn't defined anywhere
- length isn't defined anywhere
- xTrans is not defined anywhere
- zTrans is not defined anywhere
- It seems unlikely, based on what I see, that the if condition can be met:

  `xTrans >= tmp[0]-1 && xTrans < tmp[0]
   // translates to if xTrans == tmp[0] - 1`

Some other thoughts

- You're better off using `bounds.push` instead of `bounds[length] = $val`
- `for(var y=0; y<map.length ;y++) { for(var x=0; x<map[0].length ;x++) {` would be safer/faster as `var yLen = map.length; var xLen = map[0].length; for(var y=0; y<yLen ;y++) { for(var x=0; x<xLen ;x++) {`
- `bounds[length] = -y - 4 * y` is the same as `bounds[length] = -5 * y;`

Comment: I tried push and the for statement as you said and the other variables are defined but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

From you comment it seems that array is not being filled as you have some condition to fill array .
So first check you condition is being full filled or not.